# C# HttpClient POST requests from Azure Function with Authorization tag intended for third-party API are stripped of Headers and Body

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient

### UPDATE

I was able to get a working request posted. The third-party API has us sending the Token (which is basically a Guid) as a bearer token. Azure appears to do some sort of pre-validation on this. When I swapped out the GUID with a true randomly generated bearer token, it worked.

I do still wonder if there's a way to disable this check-in Azure. The "bad" Bearer token works for GET requests but fails for POST/PUT requests.

**Summary of the Application**
We have Azure Functions (i.e., Time Trigger, Orchestrator, Activities) that look for items in an on-prem queue table in SQL and then POST it to a third-party API via JSON.

The third-party API requires an Authorization header with the POST request.

**Technical Overview**

- dotnet core 3.1
- azure function runtime ~3

**Additional Information**

- This codebase worked fine during UAT back in April-May of this year. It then sat idle until we rebooted the project a couple of weeks ago.
- Outbound requests are not proxied through APIM. They're sent directly to the third-party API
- Application Insights is configured for the Azure Function

**What works**
All of the GET requests. No issues at all.

**What doesn't work**
POST requests. I proxied the requests to a beeceptor to see exactly what was being received. When the Authorization header is included most of the headers are stripped (I.e., Content-Type, Content-Length) and the Body of the request is blank.

If I removed the Authorization header then all headers and body are received as expected.

**Question**
I can only assume at this point that some Azure service, pre-flight check, security policy is intercepting the Authorization header thinking it's intended for "itself", but I have absolutely no idea what it could be. I've been on Google now for days.

**Simplified Version of Code**

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

// Request params are dynamic and a helper method builds the full request path
var path = PathBuilder(queueItem.RequestParams, queueItem.Request.UrlPath);

// This can change in code not shown if the request is sending files
var contentType = "application/json";

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(queueItem.Request.Client.BaseApiUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue { NoCache = true };
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", queueItem.Request.Client.AuthToken);

// queueItem.Data is JSON
HttpContent json = new StringContent(queueItem.Data, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);
return await client.PostAsync(path, json);
```

**Also...**

- I've confirmed the JSON body is valid
- The code did work and has remain unchanged

Comment: what happens if you copy and paste the code to a brand new Azure Function App. Do you see the same behavior (error)?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio yes. I created a new Elastic Premium Function App and redeployed everything with the same behavior. The previous was running a Standard plan. 

The same behavior is experienced in our staging environment. 

I have unit tests that run the orchestrator function locally and that works as well.

Comment: Have you tried instead of using `new AuthenticationHeaderValue(` to add the auth header like this: `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + queueItem.Request.Client.AuthToken);`?

Comment: I did. I even tried something such as .Add("Authorization", $"Token {queueItem.Request.Client.AuthToken}"); and .Add("Authorization", "alsdfjslfjalsfjlaksfjl") to eliminate the "bearer" part of the Auth header.

Comment: Silly question, but does the code work (more or less as-is) in a console app outside of Azure functions \ Azure function runtime?

Comment: It does. The Azure Activity functions consume a service layer. I have unit tests that call the "make request" service directly. That works.

Comment: i see you tried a console app. did you try running your function from under a functions CLI tool? (like, spin up a dev container and `func start` thereafter?)

Comment: For anyone finding this, I have the same issue using functions runtime v4 isolated. The Authorization headers get striped out of the call by azure functions... horrible. Still trying to find a resolution as our third party api does not allow any other method of authentication and the "key" is not a jwt.

Answer (score 1):

Given all that you’ve tried, it might be a long shot, but have you tried to add the token like:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(“Authorization”, “bearer token here…”);
```

and then check whether the try succeeded or not?

Comment: I did. I had it teed up to throw an Exception() if it failed and the condition passed (I.e., No exception was thrown).